# Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded) , Android

Tags: android, android-logcat

In logcat I found these messages, my application runs correctly (No error/ No exception/ and correct result), but why these messages appears in log cat. I closed all cursors. And one more thing, Application goes a little bit slow to displaying activity( Which activity is listed in my logcat message), I think it takes that time to generate these log messages. What is solution for this.

```
I/ActivityManager(   63): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.pankaj.myapp/.SelectedContactActivity (has extras) }
    D/dalvikvm(  251): GC freed 2584 objects / 174064 bytes in 139ms
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d2c688 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d2bf58 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d2b5a8 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d29af0 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d293c0 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d28a28 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d26f70 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d26808 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d25e60 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d24310 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d23be0 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d23238 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d21780 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d21028 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d20688 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d1ebd0 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d1e480 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d1dae0 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d1bfa0 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d1b760 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
    I/dalvikvm(  251): Ljava/lang/IllegalStateException;: Finalizing cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@43d1ac40 on contacts_tags that has not been deactivated or closed
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:596)
    I/dalvikvm(  251):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
    I/ActivityManager(   63): Displayed activity com.pankaj.myapp/.SelectedContactActivity: 2245 ms (total 2245 ms)
```

Caller Activity is using List View, And after clicking of list item "SelectedContactActivity" activity calls.

**In caller Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list_item);
        SimpleAdapter contactAdapter = getAdapter(); // This method returns SimpleAdapter object 
       // Bind to our new adapter.
       setListAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AddModifyTag.class);
        intent.putExtra("_id",contactInfo.get("_id"));
        intent.putExtra("name", contactInfo.get("name"));
        intent.putExtra("number", contactInfo.get("number"));
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_CONTACT_TAGS);
    }
```

**On called Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
......
......
        Cursor tags;
        db.open();
        tags = db.getContactTags(contactID);
        startManagingCursor(tags);
        .......
        .......
        db.close();
}
```

Comment: It seems you don't close cursors in some situations. Please, show us the code of your activity.

Comment: In caller activity I used SimpleAdapter but I did not close that adapter, is it the cause? And called Activity I am not using any Cursor.

Comment: I am experiencing the same situation. But I do not know what I should do.

Comment: Did you tried answer? If yes you should share your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are getting this error because you did not close the `Cursor` in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`. Try to close the `Cursor`. You can also use `startManagingCursor()` for you `Cursor` which will help you  to close the Cursor by Android.

Comment: But I am using SimpleAdapter, then how can I do this?

Comment: Did you use `tags.close();` in `onStop` or `OnDestroy`?

Comment: No I didn't, I am going use and check again.